# Crashed RAID of 5 hdd with 2hdd not recognised

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

I have mounted an Xpenology with 5 discs of 4TB each in a RAID SHR, which failed and after restore the disks, it does not recognize 2 of them as part of the RAID.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm -Asf
mdadm: forcing event count in /dev/sdf5(1) from 209900 upto 209914
mdadm: forcing event count in /dev/sdd5(4) from 209900 upto 209914
mdadm: clearing FAULTY flag for device 0 in /dev/md/3 for /dev/sdf5
mdadm: clearing FAULTY flag for device 2 in /dev/md/3 for /dev/sdd5
mdadm: Marking array /dev/md/3 as 'clean'
mdadm: /dev/md/3 assembled from 5 drives - not enough to start the array.
```

The data is there. Each disk has its partitions but something in the RAID information failed and does not mount it.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME            FSTYPE              SIZE MOUNTPOINT                    LABEL                      
sdb                                 3,7T                               
├─sdb1          linux_raid_member   2,4G                               
├─sdb2          linux_raid_member     2G [SWAP]                        
└─sdb5          linux_raid_member   3,6T                               NAS:3
  └─md3         LVM2_member        14,5T                               
    └─vg1000-lv ext4               14,5T                               1.42.6-5644
sdc                                 3,7T                               
├─sdc1          linux_raid_member   2,4G                               
├─sdc2          linux_raid_member     2G [SWAP]                        
└─sdc5          linux_raid_member   3,6T                               NAS:3
  └─md3         LVM2_member        14,5T                               
    └─vg1000-lv ext4               14,5T                               1.42.6-5644
sdd                                 3,7T                               
├─sdd1          linux_raid_member   2,4G                               
├─sdd2          linux_raid_member     2G [SWAP]                        
└─sdd5          linux_raid_member   3,6T                               NAS:3
  └─md3         LVM2_member        14,5T                               
    └─vg1000-lv ext4               14,5T                               1.42.6-5644
sde                                 3,7T                               
├─sde1          linux_raid_member   2,4G                               
├─sde2          linux_raid_member     2G [SWAP]                        
└─sde5          linux_raid_member   3,6T                               NAS:3
  └─md3         LVM2_member        14,5T                               
    └─vg1000-lv ext4               14,5T                               1.42.6-5644
sdf                                 3,7T                               
├─sdf1          linux_raid_member   2,4G                               
├─sdf2          linux_raid_member     2G [SWAP]                        
└─sdf5          linux_raid_member   3,6T                               NAS:3
  └─md3         LVM2_member        14,5T                               
    └─vg1000-lv ext4               14,5T                               1.42.6-5644
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disco /dev/sdb: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: gpt
Identificador del disco: A393FFF9-56A6-4151-ACC5-29428AC27C4D

Dispositivo Comienzo      Final   Sectores Tamaño Tipo
/dev/sdb1       2048    4982527    4980480   2,4G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb2    4982528    9176831    4194304     2G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb5    9453280 7813830239 7804376960   3,6T Linux RAID


Disco /dev/sdc: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: gpt
Identificador del disco: 02145928-FB41-4A17-B926-DD6DDF96A80E

Dispositivo Comienzo      Final   Sectores Tamaño Tipo
/dev/sdc1       2048    4982527    4980480   2,4G Linux RAID
/dev/sdc2    4982528    9176831    4194304     2G Linux RAID
/dev/sdc5    9453280 7813830239 7804376960   3,6T Linux RAID


Disco /dev/sdd: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: gpt
Identificador del disco: 224D3910-BE52-4A3D-989A-C777EC320EF9

Dispositivo Comienzo      Final   Sectores Tamaño Tipo
/dev/sdd1       2048    4982527    4980480   2,4G Linux RAID
/dev/sdd2    4982528    9176831    4194304     2G Linux RAID
/dev/sdd5    9453280 7813830239 7804376960   3,6T Linux RAID


Disco /dev/sde: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: gpt
Identificador del disco: 77D044E8-8DD8-4219-A024-FD696D7C0EE6

Dispositivo Comienzo      Final   Sectores Tamaño Tipo
/dev/sde1       2048    4982527    4980480   2,4G Linux RAID
/dev/sde2    4982528    9176831    4194304     2G Linux RAID
/dev/sde5    9453280 7813830239 7804376960   3,6T Linux RAID


Disco /dev/sdf: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: gpt
Identificador del disco: FC3FE7E4-1899-4743-96C1-C2937B02EFFE

Dispositivo Comienzo      Final   Sectores Tamaño Tipo
/dev/sdf1       2048    4982527    4980480   2,4G Linux RAID
/dev/sdf2    4982528    9176831    4194304     2G Linux RAID
/dev/sdf5    9453280 7813830239 7804376960   3,6T Linux RAID
```

Is there any way to recover the RAID?

Thanks for advance  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Done!!

After...

```
fsck.ext4 -yvf -C0 /dev/vg1000/lv
```

...and wait to finish, was all done.
The partition table are on error, but it works just fine , for now.